# Impossible to load any php extensions on Apache after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: php, apc, php-extension, osx-mavericks, intl

After upgrading to Mavericks, and reinstalling both `intl` and `apc` with brew I still can't load any php extensions (and specifically those two).
I keep getting the following error without any idea how to move from there:

> Wed Oct 30 18:19:15 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) PHP/5.4.17 DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.16.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Wed Oct 30 18:23:35 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   [Wed Oct 30 18:23:36 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>   httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Julien.local for ServerName
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/apc.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Do you have any idea where this can be coming from?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, along with xdebug & yaml extensions.  Hoping this comment means I'll get updates on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Found out that the php extension folder is now to be /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ instead of /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626. But php.ini hadn't been updated to point to the new extension folder.

Answer (score 0):

after updating from php 5.3 to php 5.4 apc stopped loading than i installed apc version 3.1.9 (as they say it is last good version) manually like:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.9.tgz
tar -xvf APC-3.1.9.tgz
cd APC-3.1.9
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure -enable-apc -enable-apc-mmap -with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs -with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make
make install
service httpd restart
```

**and after that apc was not loading still** than I looked for extension dir directive in php.ini and it was pointing to old dir than I checked php exstensions dir and found there new folder named no-debug-non-zts-20100525. so I fixed php.ini **extension_dir** directive for folder with new **no-debug-non-zts-20100525 folder** and it worked...